# asp.net breakpoints not hit when page is redirected to https

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis, https

I am using asp.net 4.5, forms (.aspx) , c#. I have a basic login form that basically redirects to the https version of the login form if the url is hit as http. When the url is tested under http (before the redirect) I can hit any breakpoint and also with tracing enable in the web config I can see all the tracing at the bottom of the asp page.

Once the url is redirected to the https verion then I have no breakpoints and tracing is non existent!

so (using debug config)

1 - f5 to load http://login.mysite.com/login.aspx -- > breakspoints hit in page_load handler

2 - after page_load above the user is redirected to https://login.mysite.com/login.aspx -- > no breakspoints hit and I would expect the same breakpoints to be hit (and tracing to be output)

I have tried attaching to IIS and running iis express not luck. Im using vs 2012, c#, iis 7 .net 4.5.

thanks

Comment: Please post your code from Login.aspx.cs

Comment: Could it be a browser caching issue?

Comment: Does that page load at all? Have you verified your bindings?

Comment: There are several reasons breakpoints in C# it's self, will not fire: 1) there is no successful call to the code as intended or 2) an internal error is thrown and caught without knowing, prematurely canceling the following operations. I recommend stepping through your code to make sure all paths are followed as intended - as part of the elimination process.

Comment: hi thanks for all the answers. I cant post the code as it is a form that contains 3 3rd party controls that manage the login process and they are not for public view. I am using chrome with dev tools open, probably not browser caching. The ssl cert is an iis cert so when fiddler is open it does alert some certificate errors eg when you use a test cert you have to chose the proceed option in the browser as the cert isnt verified - this might have something to do with it - e.g. iis is throwing an unhandled outside of the worker process, nothing shows up in process viewer though.

Comment: The page does load perfectly though when https, so it must be going through the page life cycle, its exactly the same aspx code that I get the breakpoints to hit when loaded non https.

Comment: I do have a breakpoint in the aspx container page within the init handler, but it could be that one of the init within the other controls is causing an exception, I vaguely remember that the ascx control lifecycle is initialised before the aspx  life cycle has gone through its paces, the odd thing is that I dont even get tracing on the https version of the page even though I have tracing enabled in the web config and I see the tracing on the http version of the page.

Comment: point 2 from Chris is my first point of call tomorrow, Ill update once Im back on the case.

Comment: turned out to a be a ssl issue, the redirect was pushed to another site on my local, that had a copy of the same page  -dah!